How to access a Kotlin private top-level property in the unnamed (main) file?
How to use Java or Kotlin reflection to access the value of a private variable in the Main.kt file?
package com.example

private val myName = "abc"

fun main() {
    println(myName)    
}


Related: How to change a kotlin private val using reflection?

val myName = Class
    .forName("com.example.MainKt") // Make sure to use the complete class name
    .getDeclaredField("myName")
    .apply { isAccessible = true }
    .get(null /* because a top-level property is static */) as String
println(myName) // abc

